# How is the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem connected to differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory, soft-question, fixed-point-theorems, arzela-ascoli

Are Banach's Fixed Point Theorem, Arzelà-Ascoli theorem, posets, and Zorn's lemma actually connected to differential equations, and how if yes?

Comment: You can used Banach's Fixed Point Theorem to prove the existence and uniqueness theorem, so that's certainly a big use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banach Fixed Point Theorem: Used to prove existence *and* uniqueness by applying it to the integral operator (which has been restricted to a contraction on a strip using the Lipschitz condition). This is called the Picard-Lindelof existence and uniqueness theorem.

Arzela-Ascoli: Used to prove just existence, by passing to a uniformly convergent subsequence in order to commute a limit and and integral. This is called the Cauchy-Peano existence theorem.

I do not know how you use the other two, they were not mentioned when I took the course.